# ASP.Net AJAX Calendar Extender not giving incorrect date via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to set the date on a text box using ASP.Net AJAX Calendar Extender control using JavaScript.

When I click on the control and select a date, I firing off the event called OnClientDateSelectionChanged. In my JavaScript I have:

```
  var fromDate = new Date();

    fromDate = sender.get_selectedDate();
    alert(fromDate);

    var toDate = new Date(fromDate)
    toDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() + 7);
    var toDateToShow = new Date(toDate);
    alert(toDateToShow);
    //alert(document.getElementById("MainContent_txtToDate"));
    document.getElementById('<%= txtToDate.ClientID%>').value = formatDate(toDateToShow);
    }
```

What I am seeing is the date for the day before as "Wed Jan 1 19:00:00 Est 2014", not 02/01/2014, which how I initially set the format up on the markup. Can someone please tell me how to correct this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem caused by environment setup incorrectly. Now corrected and is working